# Why doesn't this ES6 default argument value give the desired result?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

I found this ES6 code in a book:

```
let value = 5;

function getValue() {
    return value++;
}

function add(first, second = getValue()) {
    return first + second;
}

console.log(add(1, 1));     // 2
console.log(add(1));        // 6
```

Why does running `console.log(add(1));` return 6 as the value, which means it is taking the parameter `second` as 5 although my code explicitly specifies that the `getValue` function should return `value++` - which means the first time it is run, the `getValue` function should be returning 6 and `add` should be returning 7. I am running this code in the Firefox console - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default arguments [*are evaluated at call time*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Evaluated_at_call_time), meaning the function `getValue` invoked *every time you invoke `add`* - not when the code is initially run. Since you're using postfix increment, `getValue` will return 5 the first time you invoke `add`, then 6, 7, etc. Postfix increment returns the previous value, then increments, for example:

```
var x = 5
var foo = x++;
```

Here, `foo` is given the value 5, *then `x` is incremented*. Thus, in your example, the `getValue` function is actually returning 5 instead 6, then incrementing `value` when you first invoke it. If you want 6, 7, 8, use prefix increment which returns the value *after incrementing*:

```
++x;
```

This will increment `value`, then return that incremented value. You could even use compound addition:

```
x += 1;
```

This explicitly reassigns `x` before you access it again. Further reading on those operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).

Comment: it's not for   postfix expression it's because of Default value in function definition .

Comment: @FarhadAzarbarzinniaz And that function returns the result of postfix incrementation? Your comment is incorrect. It's precisely the reason.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewLi, @LorenzoCatalano, @AbdullahDanyal for helping me understand. However, I wonder what the use of the postfix operator is. Isn't is better to default to a prefix operator and change the value of `value` according to whether you want the numbers to start from 5 or 6

Comment: @Mortz See [this Software Engineering answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43067) -- I would say it's largely due to history that it's around today, but it can be helpful when expressing meaningful intent in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
value++
```

gets the value before increasing it,you should do either

```
++value
```

or

```
value+=1;
return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the **postfix expression**, if you use **prefix expression** then you will get 7.

[Airthmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

"If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.
If used prefix with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it returns the value after incrementing".

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is not related to `ecmascript-6`, but in not understand the `++` operator correctly.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment):

> Unary operator. Adds one to its operand. If used as a prefix operator
>   (++x), returns the value of its operand after adding one; if used as a
>   postfix operator (x++), returns the value of its operand before adding
>   one.

Replacing `value++` with either `++value` or `value + 1` should solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is called ['Default value'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) for parameters. It's mean that you can set Default value for each parameters in function definition .

```
function add(first, second = getValue()) {
    return first + second;
}
```

in this case 'second = getValue()', 'getValue()' is defulat value for 'second 'parameter.

when you do

```
console.log(add(1, 1));     // 2
```

because
first==>1 
second==>1

```
console.log(add(1));        // 6
```

because
first==>1 
second==>getValue()  ===> 6

Comment: @AndrewLi are you sure? i'm wondered how you are jugging in blind . please read question . he is new in JS6 .

Comment: I read the question -- they understand what it is, heck they even include the name in the title. The question is about why they get 6 instead of 7, which *is because of the postfix increment operator*...